# React state updates all previous elements from another state variable (React Select)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this application. I want to add the array params each unique value. But each time the "data" state gets changed. But I didnt apply the change to the data, but to the params. So each time I select the same value as before the previous elements get updated.

```
function App() {   
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null)
  const [params, setParams] = useState([])
 
  const [data, setData] = useState([{"value":"AAA","label":"AAA"}, {"value":"BB","label":"BBB"} ])

  const handleChange = (selected) => {     
    setSelected(selected)
    const a = selected
    a.label = a.label + params.length
    setParams(state=> [...state, a ])   
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">      
        <label>Add Data: </label> 

         {params.map((param) => {
          if(param && param.value){
            return<div>{param.label}</div>          
          }})}

        <Select className = "select4"
            value={selected}
            onChange={handleChange}
            options={data}
          /> 
        <br />
        
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here whats happening, I dont want to have them changed, I want unique AAA1, AAA2, AAA3
[image]

Update after adding `if (!params.includes(selected)) {` to setParams.

2nd image
[image]

I want to add "AAA0", "AAA1", "AAA2" and so on..

Comment: There is no logic in your code which validates if the `params` variable already contains the selected value. Since you are using the same referenced objects, you can wrap the `setParams` with `if (!params.includes(selected)) {` to check if it already exists.

Comment: I tried but now it just doesnt add to new parameters at all. and instead the label changes on my data. I updated the 2nd image on the post. I want to add new paratemers with different index each time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are overwriting the values in your 'data' array and then adding them in the 'params' state. Try to create a new object modifying this line in the handleChange function:

From this
const a = selected

To this
const a = { ...selected }